# Building a Compound Computation

Tags: haskell, monads, scientific-computing

I have a few different computations that I'd like to do on a set of data. These computations have some common subcomputations which end up being re-evaluated, so what I'd like to do is build up a "compound computation" which does everything at once and shares the data. I feel like there's a monad for this, but I don't know its name.

I'm really interested in the abstract aspect of this, but to be less vague the actual situation is the following: I have a 2D grid which I'm doing a simulation on and so I'm computing local values (derivatives etc.) using a stencil and then combining them to step my simulation forward in time. Here's a simple example:

```
import Data.Array.Accelerate
type Local  = Stencil3x3 Double -> Exp Double

convect :: Local
convect s@((_,t,_),(l,c,r),(_,b,_)) =
    c+c0*(dx s +dy s)
    where c0 = 1e-2

dx :: Local
dx ((_,t,_),(l,c,r),(_,b,_)) = 0.5*(l-r)
```

(But I could just as easily not be using Accelerate and stencils here.)

I know I could just lump this all into one function, but that wouldn't be very elegant or resuable or haskelly.

Is there a nice way where I could tell `convect`, "I'm going to want these values, go off and get them all at once please"?

Comment: While I'm at it, trying to cast these stencils into something comonad-ey, it occurs to me I don't really know quite what you're asking for. In particular, what's your objection against simply doing it all with `dx` and `dy`? Those pattern matches could be greatly reduced (`convect` doesn't need the `@` at all, and you could write `dx (_,(l,_,r),_) = (l-r)/2`), then it looks pretty much ideal.

Comment: Well unless the compiler optimises it out, it seems to me like calculating `dx s` will take one pass over the array and `dy s` a second one. I could expand the pattern as you've done, but as it is currently I can import StencilDerviatives3x3 and use the current form, or without changing anything else use import StencilDerivatives5x5 which I've defined similarly, unless you're suggesting I implement convect separately for each stencil type.

Comment: Don't worry about performance there. These stencil functions are only evaluated exactly once, before compiling the CUDA kernel (or what other backend you're using), and how that's going to end up has nothing to do with multiply-evaluated arguments of the stencil. The stencils don't even _know_ anything about arrays. — I'll leave my answer as it is because this kind of thing can indeed be done with a comonad – but that wouldn't solve your performance concern at all, indeed it would almost certainly be slower.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like an application for the (2D) [array comonad](http://blog.sigfpe.com/2008/03/comonadic-arrays.html)!

Comment: Is that not what I'm already getting from the stencil? I realise I left out the full form of the type signature above, I'll fix that. I know that I can just write out the full expanded (in terms of `t,l,c,r,b` rather than `dx`) expression each time, but I want some way (or its equivalent) to do that functionally. If you think that that's possible with the array comonad could you elaborate please?

Comment: Yeah. Perhaps you could add your grid types etc. so I can adapt my explanation to them?

Comment: The grid is just a `Array DIM2 Double`, or rather `Acc (Array DIM2 Double)` since this is happening in the context of an Accelerate computation.

Comment: Interesting! I'm afraid Accelerate _does_ rather complicate entering the Array comonad, at least the ordinary array+index implementation obviously doesn't work. It should certainly be possible though – indeed a stencil function is already almost exactly a Cokleisli arrow. Hmm...